# error: called object type 'double' is not a function or function pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I am relatively new to c++ programming, I have an assignment to code the Newton Raphson method however I have the error error:

```
called object type 'double' is not a function or function pointer
```

This error appears when I am trying to compile my code. I tried some basic changes to assign pointer but I probably did it in the wrong way, my code is printed below, can anybody explain how can I overcome this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

double f(double x); //this is f(x)
double f(double x) {
  double eq1 = exp(x) + pow(x,3) + 5;
  return eq1;
}

double f1(double x); //this is the first derivative f'(x)
double f1(double x) {
  double eq2 = exp(x) + 3*pow(x,2);
  return eq2;
}

int main() {
  double x, xn, f, f1, eps;
  cout << "Select first root :" << '\n'; //Here we select our first guess
  cin >> xn; 
  cout << "Select Epsilon accuracy :" << '\n';
  cin >> epsi;
  f = f(x);
  f1 = f1(x);
  cout << "x_n" << " " << "x_(n+1)"  << " " << "|x_(n+1) - x_1|" << '\n';
  do { 
    x = xn; //This is the first iteneration step where x takes the value of the last itenarated (known) root xn
    f = f(x);
    f1 = f1(x);
    xn = x - (f/f1); //this the formula that sets the itenaration going 
    cout << x << "     " << xn << "          " << fabs(xn - x) << '\n';
  }

  while( fabs(xn - x) < epsi ); //If |x_(n+1) - x_n| is smaller than the desired accurcay than the itenaration continues 
  cout << "The root of the equation is " << xn << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [MCVE] please that reproduces the error.

Comment: in which line is the error? Where is the pointer you are talking about? And btw it is "iteration" not "iteneration"

Comment: you dont need to forward declare the functions if you dont use them before they are defined.

Answer (score 3):

You have local variables with the same name as the functions, thus

```
f = f(x);
f1 = f1(x);
```

cannot work.

Rename either the functions or the variables. Anyhow single letter variable/function names are not nice. Use descriptive names. You (or anybody else) taking a look at the code after some weeks will be thankful for that.

PS: you also dont need the forward declarations. And the functions can be written a bit shorter:

```
//double f(double x); //  this you dont need
double f(double x) {
    return exp(x) + pow(x,3) + 5;
}
```

Also [`using namespace std;` is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). In this case it does little to no harm, but you better get rid of this bad habit before it does matter.

Last but not least you should format your code properly. This

```
while( fabs(xn - x) < epsi );
```

looks very nasty, because it seems to be an infinite loop. I almost never use the do-while loop, however, I suggest you to write it like this:

```
do {
   // ...
} while ();
```

because usually whenever you see a while with a `;` in the same line you should start to panic ;) (while loops are much more common than do-while and errors caused by a `;` after the condition in a while loop can be a pain in the a** to debug)

Comment: Thanks, this cleared everything, the code works perfectly now :)

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to use functions called f and f1 and doubles called f and f1.  If you call the variables or the function something else, then you can resolve the error.  It would be good coding practice to give these variables better names that tell the reader what they do and avoid mistakes like this one.

Comment: Thank you, yes it seems clear now that you explain it, I am still new and make plenty of this inaccuracies.

Answer (score 0):

There were several errors in your code. I made it compilable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

double func(double x); //this is f(x)
double func(double x) {
  double eq1 = exp(x) + pow(x,3) + 5;
  return eq1;
}

double func1(double x); //this is the first derivative f'(x)
double func1(double x) {
  double eq2 = exp(x) + 3*pow(x,2);
  return eq2;
}

int main() {
  double x, xn, f, f1, eps;
  cout << "Select first root :" << '\n'; //Here we select our first guess
  cin >> xn; 
  cout << "Select Epsilon accuracy :" << '\n';
  cin >> eps;
  f = func(x);
  f1 = func1(x);
  cout << "x_n" << " " << "x_(n+1)"  << " " << "|x_(n+1) - x_1|" << '\n';
  do { 
    x = xn; //This is the first iteneration step where x takes the value of the last itenarated (known) root xn
    f = func(x);
    f1 = func1(x);
    xn = x - (f/f1); //this the formula that sets the itenaration going 
    cout << x << "     " << xn << "          " << fabs(xn - x) << '\n';
  }

  while( fabs(xn - x) < eps ); //If |x_(n+1) - x_n| is smaller than the desired accurcay than the itenaration continues 
  cout << "The root of the equation is " << xn << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

The main problems were:

1. you defined the variable `f` with the same name of the `f(x)` function  (the same error was repeated for the `f'(x)` function) and
2. you declared the `eps` variable to represent *epsilon* in your program but you tried to access to it several times by calling it `epsi`.